# My direct reports bypassing me and leadership allows it

Tags: management, india, people-management

I am facing sort of a issue (not major problem though). Couple of my direct reports bypasses me sometimes and directly goes to my boss say for eg: My Laptop is not working, need to escalate, when will promotions happens etc and my boss responds to them, we have open culture so anyone can go to any level and talk to them.

The problem is I will not be knowing they have directly gone to my boss and sometimes their problem got solved without first line manager involved (it's me). I regularly have 1-1s with them, will be humble, ask them for any issues or problems they have. In the 1-1 meetings they say no issues at all and in backend they would approach my boss.

How do I handle this situation? I am pretty new to this company though, this is not happening with all people, I manage a team of 7 and only couple of them do this. Any suggestions, inputs etc would be helpful to improve this situation. First time I am doing direct people management.

It's a Indian branch of a US based company.

Comment: Why downvote? Any comment to improve would be helpful

Comment: "The problem is I will not be knowing they have directly gone to my boss and sometimes their problem got solved without first line manager involved (it's me)." Why is this a problem?

Comment: As their manager I should be knowing right what issue they are facing? and if every time directly bypasses me what's the use of my role?

Comment: That all seems to be _your_ problem, not your team's or your employer's problem. Maybe you should talk to your manager about what they think your role is.

Comment: My role is Manager and those people are reporting to me, might be you are not understanding my question :)

Comment: Are those problems something you need to be informed about to do a good job, or are they closed after they have been resolved? Do you solve the same problems for the others, or do they just not have those problems?

Comment: @nvoigt Yes I need to be informed about it. It's not problem with all, 5 out of 7 people follows chain of command, only problem with couple of people.

Comment: Do you get informed afterwards, or are you just missing the information?

Comment: @NarasimhaSharma I am absolutely understanding your question - to be blunt, you seem to want to be a traditional "command and control" manager who has to be involved in every single bit of your team's business. I think that is a terrible way to manage.

Comment: @nvoigt Information is missing

Comment: @PhilipKendall Please see the country tag :) Work culture differs across world it's sort of different in India than western countries, here the way team and people works is different so manager needs to be aware of what's happening in team (not micromanaging). The way people managed here is different than US/UK etc.

Comment: In your question you write that your boss says to all this that you have an open culture so anyone can speak directly to any level, but then in the comments you say that in your workplace people need to follow a chain of commands. They can't be both true at the same time. Is it you that want to establish the strict chain of command and cannot deal with people living the open culture?

Answer (score 9):

You said:

> My direct reports bypassing me and leadership allows it

and

> we have open culture so anyone can go to any level and talk to them.

This is the answer to your "issue".  Your company culture encourages this behavior so it should be no surprise and no issue when your employees adhere to this.

> First time I am doing direct people management.

People management doesn't mean that you control every aspect of everything that they do and that they should not communicate with people higher in the company hierarchy before communicating with you.  If you are having issues with how your employees are behaving you can always speak to your boss and ask them for guidance on handling the "situation".  But if the company culture is as you have described, don't be surprised when your boss tells you that there is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your own boss what to expect in this situation.

If your bosses expect an open culture, then they expect this to happen. There is nothing wrong with the presented scenario.

However, if your bosses expect you to magically know everything, then that's a problem. Ask your own boss what their expectations are of you when your "reports" skip you. Their response will give you a roadmap on what you need to do.